# Join two files including unmatched lines in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

File1.log

```
207.46.13.90  37556
157.55.39.51  34268
40.77.167.109 21824
157.55.39.253 19683
```

File2.log

```
207.46.13.90  62343
157.55.39.51  58451
157.55.39.200 37675
40.77.167.109 21824
```

Below should be expected 
Output.log

```
207.46.13.90    37556   62343
157.55.39.51    34268   58451
157.55.39.200   -----   37675
40.77.167.109   21824   21824
157.55.39.253   19683   -----
```

I tried with the below 'join' command - but it skips the missing line

```
join --nocheck-order File1.log File2.log
```

outputting like below (not as expected)

```
207.46.13.90  37556 62343
157.55.39.51  34268 58451
40.77.167.109 21824 21824
```

Could someone please help with the proper command for the desired output. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use `--nocheck-order` and expect it to work. It will not work and just not print any error message. `join` needs the input to be sorted.

Comment: Thanks - but I have already sorted File1 & File2 based on the second column

Comment: But you want to join on the first column, so you need to sort both files on the first column.

Comment: But those are IPs and I want the desired output to show the increase trend of the counts - second column is the count of the number of IPs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
($1 in a){
  print $0,a[$1]
  b[$1]
  next
}
{
  print $1,$2 " ----- "
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(!(i in b)){
      print i" ----- "a[i]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
207.46.13.90  37556 62343
157.55.39.51  34268 58451
40.77.167.109 21824 21824
157.55.39.253 19683 -----
157.55.39.200 ----- 37675
```

Comment: Sure - one more addition - I'm trying join another new file file3.log and now the output of the 3rd file should append to the above one which collate all the 3 file's stats. with the above one it over-writes if I try to merge the third file.

Comment: @user2170023: Please post a separate question for 3 file problem. Adding that through comments changes nature of the problem you asked here.

Comment: @user2170023,IMHO it will be a complete new requirement all solutions given were written for 2 files, you could open new thread for same, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The following is just enough if you don't care about sorting order of the output:

```
join -a1 -a2 -e----- -oauto <(sort file1.log) <(sort file2.log) |
column -t -s' ' -o'   '
```

with recreation of the input files:

```
cat <<EOF >file1.log
207.46.13.90  37556
157.55.39.51  34268
40.77.167.109 21824
157.55.39.253 19683
EOF
cat <<EOF >file2.log
207.46.13.90  62343
157.55.39.51  58451
157.55.39.200 37675
40.77.167.109 21824
EOF
```

outputs:

```
157.55.39.200   -----   37675
157.55.39.253   19683   -----
157.55.39.51    34268   58451
207.46.13.90    37556   62343
40.77.167.109   21824   21824
```

`join` by default joins by the first columns. The `-a1 -a2` make it print the unmatched lines from both inputs. The `-e-----` prints unknown columns as dots. The `-oauto` determinates the output from the columns of the inputs. Because we want to sort on the first column, we don't need to specif `-k1` to `sort`, but `sort -s -k1` could speed things up. To match the expected output, I also piped to `column`.

You can sort the output by ports by pipeing it to for example to `sort -rnk2,3`.

Comment: It works.. yeah...!!! Though I'm happy with the output, it will be better to get the sorted kind which is sent by Ravinder as above.. Thanks again for your effort.. you saved my day..