# Merge multiple files to a single file including unmatched lines in shell

Tags: linux, shell, join, awk

File1.log

```
207.46.13.90  37556
157.55.39.51  34268
40.77.167.109 21824
157.55.39.253 19683
```

File2.log

```
207.46.13.90  62343
157.55.39.51  58451
157.55.39.200 37675
40.77.167.109 21824
```

File3.log

```
207.46.13.90  85343
157.55.39.51  59876
157.55.39.200 37675
157.55.39.253 19683
```

Below should be expected history.log

```
207.46.13.90    37556   62343   85343
157.55.39.51    34268   58451   59876
157.55.39.200   -----   37675   37675
40.77.167.109   21824   21824   -----
157.55.39.253   19683   -----   19683
```

Using Join doesn't work - And I could attain with 2 files as suggested by Ravinder in the other thread: [Join two files including unmatched lines in Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394583/join-two-files-including-unmatched-lines-in-shell)

Also, in the next run I would be adding another file4.log to the say history.log as a 4th column. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `gnu awk` to combine multiple files with same key as first column value:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{
   a[$1][ARGIND] = $2
}
END {
   for (i in a) {
      printf "%s", i
      for (j=1; j<ARGC; j++)
         printf "%s", OFS (j in a[i] ? a[i][j] : "-----")
      print ""
   }
}' File*.log
```

```
207.46.13.90    37556   62343   85343
40.77.167.109   21824   21824   -----
157.55.39.51    34268   58451   59876
157.55.39.253   19683   -----   19683
157.55.39.200   -----   37675   37675
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. This should work for more than 3 Input_files too(though tested with OP's sample 3 Input_file(s) only but should work).

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  count++
}
{
  a[$1]
  b[count,$1]=$2
}
END{
  for(j in a){
    for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
      printf("%s%s%s",i==1?j OFS:"",b[i,j]?b[i,j]:" ----- ",i==count?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2  Input_file3 | column -t
```

Output will be as follows.

```
207.46.13.90   37556  62343  85343
40.77.167.109  21824  21824  -----
157.55.39.51   34268  58451  59876
157.55.39.253  19683  -----  19683
157.55.39.200  -----  37675  37675
```

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                                                                              ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==1{                                                                            ##Checking condition if this is first line then do following.
  count++                                                                          ##Creating a variable count whose value is increasing each time FNR==1 for each Input_file first line.
}
{
  a[$1]                                                                            ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1 first field of current line for Input_file(s).
  b[count,$1]=$2                                                                   ##Creating an array named b whose index is count,$1 and value is $2 of current line.
}
END{                                                                               ##Starting END BLOCK for this awk program here.
  for(j in a){                                                                     ##Looping through array a all elements from here.
    for(i=1;i<=count;i++){                                                         ##Running a for loop from i=1 till value of count.
      printf("%s%s%s",i==1?j OFS:"",b[i,j]?b[i,j]:" ----- ",i==count?ORS:OFS)      ##Using printf statement where first condition its checking is i==1 TRUE then print j OFS OR print NULL, checking condition if element b[i,j] is NOT NULL then print its value else print NULL. Final condition is if i==count then print new line else print space.
    }                                                                              ##Closing BLOCK for, for loop of i=1 to i<=count.
  }                                                                                ##Closing BLLOCK for, for loop (j in a) here.
}                                                                                  ##Closing BLOCK for END BLOCK of this awk program.
'  Input_file1  Input_file2  Input_file3 | column -t                               ##Mentioning Input_file names here and sending its output to column -t command to get correct spaces in output.
```

Comment: Thanks for code - sorry I am not clear with the question. I'm not merging all 3 files at a stretch. I will be appending history.log + 1 newly generated file. so that it adds just the column, and for the fourth time I need to add count to the fourth column to the history.log

Comment: @user2170023, So you mean your number of files are not set and they will keep increasing right?

Comment: correct, for each run I will be appending a new file to the history.log

Comment: @user2170023, then this code should take care of this, can you please try it once with 3 files and then 4 and so on and lemme know then?

Comment: '  history.log iplog_new.log | column -t >> history.log

Comment: The above is the argument I'm passing, but the history.log is appending below the existing content

Comment: @user2170023, can you please tell me what happens if you only run command till ` column -t` lemme know please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204539/discussion-between-user2170023-and-ravindersingh13).

Answer (score 1):

Using `join`, it's a 2-step process: note that join requires its input to be lexically sorted

1. first you need to join the first 2 files:

   ```sh
   join -a 1 -a 2 -e "-----" -o "0,1.2,2.2" <(sort File1.log) <(sort File2.log)
   ```

   ```
   157.55.39.200 ----- 37675
   157.55.39.253 19683 -----
   157.55.39.51 34268 58451
   207.46.13.90 37556 62343
   40.77.167.109 21824 21824
   ```
2. then join *that output* with file 3:

   ```sh
   join -a 1 -a 2 -e "-----" -o "0,1.2,1.3,2.2" \
     <( join -a 1 -a 2 -e "-----" -o "0,1.2,2.2" <(sort File1.log) <(sort File2.log) ) \
     <(sort File3.log)
   ```

   ```
   157.55.39.200 ----- 37675 37675
   157.55.39.253 19683 ----- 19683
   157.55.39.51 34268 58451 59876
   207.46.13.90 37556 62343 85343
   40.77.167.109 21824 21824 -----
   ```
3. if you want, tidy the output with `column`:

   ```sh
   join -a 1 -a 2 -e "-----" -o "0,1.2,1.3,2.2" \
     <( join -a 1 -a 2 -e "-----" -o "0,1.2,2.2" <(sort File1.log) <(sort File2.log) ) \
     <(sort File3.log) \
     | column -t
   ```

   ```
   157.55.39.200  -----  37675  37675
   157.55.39.253  19683  -----  19683
   157.55.39.51   34268  58451  59876
   207.46.13.90   37556  62343  85343
   40.77.167.109  21824  21824  -----
   ```