# filter then merge output of 2 commands on a line level

Tags: bash, shell, grep, ksqldb

Premis: i'm using run-ksql-test utility which has the output described in commands ouput section
I have test files with the following output
I just want to map the test status with the filename, and due to some devops restrictions I must use shell or bash only

setup:

test file format:

```
--@test: test Name 1
<multiple sql statements>
--@test: testName2
<multiple sql statements>
--@test: test Name3
<multiple sql statements>
```

command's output:

```
N number of lines with no perticular format, but wihtout ">>>"
[<timestamp>]: >>> Test Passed
N number of lines with no perticular format, but wihtout ">>>"
[<timestamp>]: >>> Test Passed
N number of lines with no perticular format, but wihtout ">>>"
[<timestamp>]: >>> Test Failed
N number of lines with no perticular format, but wihtout ">>>"
```

results i want:

```
--@test: test Name 1    [<timestamp>]: >>> Test Passed
--@test: testName2    [<timestamp>]: >>> Test Passed
--@test: test Name3    [<timestamp>]: >>> Test Failed
```

note that I need the entire lines from both commands

constraints:
only shell code
if possible use out of awk, grep, tr, cut, cat, sed or any other utility generally available by default in linux / unix , if you must that's fine i can test on my end

iv'e read many similar question including  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59396273/merge-multiple-files-to-a-single-file-including-unmatched-lines-in-shell) but i dont understand the awk to be able to modify this for my use as there's no key with which i can match two different rows

here's a small snippet of the code i'm using

```
do
    echo "---------------- TESTING $test_file ----------------"
    run-ksql-test --test-directory $test_file --temp-folder $TEMP_FOLDER  > $LOG_DIR/$(basename $test_file)
    
    #take Names Of the tests from assembled query file
    test_names=($(cat $test_file | grep -Eo  '\-\-\@.*'))  #also tried similar variations but outupt is either one chunk or broken into words 


    #take results from the logs for that file
    test_results=($(cat $LOG_DIR/$(basename $test_file) | grep -Eoi '>>>+(Passed|Failed)'))

    for ((i=0; i<${#test_names[@]}; i++)); do
        echo "${test_names[i]} ${test_results[i]}"
    done
    sleep 3

done
```

this is breaking outputs on word level and trying to echo them which is not the desired format

Comment: May be `paste <(grep "^--@" "$testfile") <(grep ">>>" "$LOG_DIR/$(basename "$test_file")")`.

Comment: thanks a lot this is elegant,  just that if you're on macOS use bash specifically

Answer (score 1):

Basically your algorithm is reasonable. The problem is in building the array `test_names`. The result of the `grep` is something like

```
@test foo
@test bar
...
```

which populates your array with

```
( @test foo @test bar .... )
```

while you need only

```
( foo bar ... )
```

You did not tell us the syntax of your test names, but if you can guarantee, that the names themselves don't have imbedded white space, you could do a

```
test_names=( $(grep -Eo '@test +[^ ]+' $test_file | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' ' )
```

The `tr` replaces each run of spaces by a single space, which is necessary for `cut` to find the second field.

**UPDATE**

If the test name can contain any character, i.e. stretches from the first non-blank character after *@test* up to the end of the line, we can do a

```
readarry -t test_names < <(grep @test "$test_file" | sed 's/--@test *//')
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I want to leave the test naming up to the person writing the test. if i use this and the test name has a space we'll get only the first word is it possible to get a range from the second word to the end? 

Also, i assume this would not directly work with the logs file of the command output, i see we're taking the 2nd result from cut, but for command's log i need the entire line.

Comment: @dragonLOLz : Sure, but in this case, the naming conventions should be defined in the question. I just proposed my solution based on the fact that in those testing frameworks I had worked so far, test names indeed where always just identifiers. If this is different in the OP's case, he will put a comment on my answer and edit his question accordingly, and then I can update my answer to cover the naming of the OP.

Comment: sorry i was just editing the above comment

Comment: to be more specific i want an entire line to be a single element in the list/arrays created,

Comment: also is it possible to index the second file while i use the  ` for i in "${test_names[@]}" ` syntex

Comment: @dragonLOLz : I updated my solution, but note that such details about the format of the input file should be put into the question.

Comment: @dragonLOLz : Good point: Since you need to loop over both files, you indeed need a counting loop. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '
    NR==FNR { if (/^--@/) tests[++x]=$0; next }
    /: >>>/ { print tests[++y], $0 }
' testfile cmdoutput
--@test: test Name 1    [<timestamp>]: >>> Test Passed
--@test: testName2      [<timestamp>]: >>> Test Passed
--@test: test Name3     [<timestamp>]: >>> Test Failed
```